# Is it possible to compare values of a dictionary with an int without using dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d = {}
d[3] = 0
d[1] = 4
```

I tried

```
mask = d > 1    # TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int'
mask = d.values > 1    # TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

Both aren't correct. Is it possible to perform the computation without using dictionary comprehension?

The desired output would be:

```
{3: False, 1: True}
```

Comment: `[x > 1 for x in d.values()]
`

Comment: *without using a dict comprehension* - yes- you could use a plain loop, although that's probably not the answer you're looking for. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. What's the desired output?

Comment: `[k for k, x in d.items() if x > 1]` is another consideration

Comment: @pault The expected output should be another dictionary `{3: Fasle, 1:True}`

Comment: You're going to need to use some sort of loop or comprehension. For example, some options: `dict((k, v>1) for k, v in d.items())` or `dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1]> 1), d.items()))` but IMO the dict comprehension: `{k: v>1 for k, v in d.items()}` is the pythonic way to do this.

Comment: I'd consider the list comprehension the preferred method. Why are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 4):

I feel like what you want is the ability to actually write `d < 5` and magically get a new dictionary (which I don't think is possible with plain `dict()`). But on the other hand I thought this was a great idea, so I implemented a first version:

```py
"""Here is our strategy for implementing this: 

 1) Inherit the abstract Mapping which define a 
 set of rules — interface — we will have to respect 
 to be considered a legitimate mapping class. 

 2) We will implement that by delegating all the hard 
 work to an inner dict().

 3) And we will finally add some methods to be able 
 to use comparison operators.
""" 
import collections
import operator

"Here is step 1)"
class MyDict(collections.abc.MutableMapping):

  "step 2)"
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.content = dict(*args)

  # All kinds of delegation to the inner dict: 
  def __iter__(self): return iter(self.content.items())
  def __len__(self): return len(self.content)
  def __getitem__(self, key): return self.content[key]
  def __setitem__(self, key, value): self.content[key] = value
  def __delitem__(self, key): del self.content[key]
  def __str__(self): return str(self.content)

  "And finally, step 3)"
  # Build where function using the given comparison operator
  def _where_using(comparison):

    def where(self, other):
      # MyDict({...}) is optional
      # you could just decide to return a plain dict: {...}
      return MyDict({k: comparison(v, other) for k,v in self})

    return where

  # map all operators to the corresponding "where" method:
  __lt__ = _where_using(operator.lt)
  __le__ = _where_using(operator.le)
  __eq__ = _where_using(operator.eq)
  __gt__ = _where_using(operator.gt)
  __ge__ = _where_using(operator.ge)
```

We can use this the way you asked for:

```py
>>> d = MyDict({3:0, 1:4})
>>> print(d)
{3: 0, 1: 4}
>>> print(d > 1)
{3: False, 1: True}
```

Note that this would also work on other types of (comparable) objects:

```py
>>> d = MyDict({3:"abcd", 1:"abce"})
>>> print(d)
{3: 'abcd', 1: 'abce'}
>>> print(d > "abcd")
{3: False, 1: True}
>>> print(d > "abcc")
{3: True, 1: True}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way for you to use something like `d<5`. You just need:

```py
import pandas as pd
res = pd.Series(d) < 4 
res.to_dict()  # returns {3: True, 1: False}`
```

Comment: This returns `{1: False}` not `{3: True, 1: False}` I guess you need to remove the `index`.

Comment: @cglacet I'll change the code. There's a small typo here :) Thanks for pointing that out.